# Upper bounding a sum of exponentials

Tags: analysis, summation, exponential-sum

Define
$$\phi(a,b,k) = e^{-a/b} + e^{-a/(b+1)} + \cdots + e^{-a/(b+k)}.$$
For example, 
$$\phi(10,2,3) = e^{-10/2} + e^{-10/3} + e^{-10/4} + e^{-10/5}, $$
or
$$\phi(10,2,3) = e^{-5} + e^{-3.33..} + e^{-2.25} + e^{-2}.$$
We will assume that $a,b$ are positive integers, $a>b$, and $k$ is an integer.

I need to upper bound this. Intuitively, it seems clear that only the last terms of the sum really matter, so something like 
$$\phi(a,b,k) \approx e^{-a/(b+k)}$$ should hold
where $\approx$ perhaps hides some moderately growing function. What is a formal statement that captures this?

Answer (score 1):

How about noting that since $x\mapsto e^{-x}$ is a decreasing function, you have that $e^{-a/(b+j)}\leq e^{-a/(b+k)}$ for all $k\geq j\geq 0$, and then bound your function naively by

\begin{align*}
\phi(a,b,k) &= e^{-a/b} + e^{-a/(b+1)} + \cdots + e^{-a/(b+k)}\\
&\leq e^{-a/(b+k)}+e^{-a/(b+k)}+\cdots+e^{-a/(b+k)}\\
&= (k+1)e^{-a/(b+k)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Right, I agree that is true. I was wondering if you could do better, by replacing that $k+1$ with something that grows more slowly.